# Which way is a best to fetch data in node js from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, fetch

everyone I have such a question, I fetch data in node js from MongoDB, also I Have two routes where was fetched "users" and "posts", check the code:

```
// Mongoose schema models
const users = require('../models/users')
const posts = require('../models/posts')

routes.get('/users', (req, res) => {
   users.find({}, (err, users) => {
        res.end(users)
   })
})

routes.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
   posts.find({}, (err, posts) => {
        res.end(posts)
   })
})
```

What do you think? it is right? I know it works, but I want to know if it's good or if I can do better. also, consider that I get those data in react js and then I filter as I want and where I want. in addition, I want to get advice about redux, what do you think? it's necessary to use it when we get data? Share your opinion

thank's

Comment: What is the other way?

Comment: I feel like I'm not doing something right :)

Comment: how big will your collections get? It's probably not a bad idea to implement some pagination logic right at the beginning :)

Comment: It's not a big collection, but let's say we have a big collection

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a DB is a async operation and you'll have to await the answer.

```
router.get('/users', async (req, res) => {   
  const users = await User.find().sort('name');   
  res.send(users); 
})
```

Comment: Well, he did use a callback, which is a valid alternativ to using promises. I also like promises better, but I think this is debatable in such a simple case.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much it if you just want to fetch all the data and return it to the frontend.

However, I would suggest one addition to your query, and that is adding the `.lean()` to the query since it will increase the performance. By default, Mongoose will hydrate the data before returning it, so when you add `.lean()`, it will tell Mongoose that it should skip the hydration of the data and return the pure JavaScript objects.

Also, you should have error handling in case of an error.

```js
// Mongoose schema models
const Users = require('../models/users')
const Posts = require('../models/posts')

routes.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
   try {
     const users = await Users.find().lean();
     return res.status(200).json(users);
   } catch (error) {
     return res.status(400).json({ success: false });
   }
})

routes.get('/posts', async (req, res) => {
   try {
     const posts = await Posts.find().lean();
     return res.status(200).json(posts);
   } catch (error) {
     return res.status(400).json({ success: false });
   }
})
```